# strtolower and similar functions with wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, echo, str-replace

Hi am trying to figure out how to use the strolower function and strtolower + str_replace function with the following code - `<?php echo get_the_author_meta('custom_field_35', $user->ID); ?>`

This is what I have so far but it's not working -

```
 <?php
$str = "echo get_the_author_meta('custom_field_35', $user->ID);";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; // Prints mary had a little lamb and she loved it so
?>

<?php $get_the_author_meta('custom_field_36', $user->ID) = strtolower(str_replace(",", "",$get_the_author_meta('custom_field_35', $user->ID))); ?>
```

How can I use strtolower and str_replace with get_the_author_meta?

Comment: You can't set a function to a value like that. You would have to apply the strtolower and str_replace and then store the result in a variable.

Comment: @Marc B I had it like that because I was trying different things to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: trying things like that would be a sign of cargo-cult programming. doing things with no real understanding of why.

Comment: @Supericy Can u explain how I can do this or provide an example?

Comment: @Marc B I am not that familiar with php or the function, so yes I was just trying that code to see what happens. I still need to know how to accomplish this task though. Do you have any relevant information or examples that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I did not need to go back to learn basic PHP syntax rules, I was able to figure it out myself.

In case anyone else wants to know how I did it -

```
<?php
      $f_states = get_the_author_meta( 'custom_field_35', $user->ID, true );
$f_pr = get_the_author_meta( 'custom_field_36', $user->ID, true );
?>
<?php Print(strtolower(str_replace(",", "",$f_pr))); ?> <?php Print(strtolower($f_states)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strtolower and str_replace at the bottom look fine, but you can't assign to this:
`$get_the_author_meta('custom_field_36', $user->ID)`

You would be better off just having:

`<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(",", "",$get_the_author_meta('custom_field_35', $user->ID))); ?>`

Or putting it into a variable and echoing that:

`<?php $var = strtolower(str_replace(",", "",$get_the_author_meta('custom_field_35', $user->ID)));`

`echo $var; ?>`

Comment: Hi I tried using both your suggestions and received this error - "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in..."

Comment: The code I had is the one I placed in my original question. I had to remove the code from my page because I kept getting errors. What I am basically trying to do is make the author meta echo out in lowercase and another function to make it lowercase and remove a comma.